# ok Google-like hotword listener

Tags: android, detection

I'm currently programming a search engine application and would like to let the app listen to a hotword when I'm in the app, like Google with "Ok Google". How can I let the app listen for that and how can I let it start a certain function?

To be exact, this function:

```
btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "de-DE");

            try {
                startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);
                txtText.setText("");
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Ihr Gerät unterstützt kein Sprache-Zu-Text-System!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that but using external API, check how keyword activation is implemented in pocketsphinx

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid